# Find the even sum and even max

Tags: java, algorithm, sum, max, java.util.scanner

I am trying to find the even sum and even max from numbers inputted by the user. For example, if they answered "How many integers?" with 4 and inputted the integers: 2, 9, 18, 4 it should output:

```
how many integers? 4
next integer? 2
next integer? 9
next integer? 18
next integer? 4
even sum = 24
even max = 18
```

Here is my code:

```
    public static void evenSum(){
        //prompt the user to enter the amount of integers
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("how many integers? ");
        int numbers = console.nextInt();
        //prompt user to enter the first integer
        System.out.print("next integer? ");
        int firstNum = console.nextInt();
        //set the even max to the firstNum
        int evenMax = firstNum;
        //set the evenSum to zero
        int evenSum = 0;
        //for loop for the number of times to ask user to input numbers
        for (int i = 2; i <= numbers; i++) {
            System.out.print("next integer? ");
            int num = console.nextInt();
            //check to see if the first number is even
            if (firstNum % 2 == 0){
            //if it is even then add it to the evenSum
                evenSum += firstNum;
            }
            //check to see if the numbers entered are even
            if (num % 2 == 0) {
            //if they are even add them to the evenSum
                evenSum += num;
            }
            //check to see if the number entered is bigger than the first number
            if (num > firstNum) {
                if (num % 2 == 0 ) {
                    evenMax = num;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("even sum = " +evenSum);
        System.out.println("even max = " +evenMax);
}
```

But here is what is my output is:

```
how many integers? 4
next integer? 2
next integer? 9
next integer? 18
next integer? 4
even sum = 28
even max = 4
```

Could someone help me figure out what the problem is?

Comment: In your for loop, you add at each iteration `firstNum` to `evenNum` if `firstNum` is even. Move `if (firstNum % 2 == 0){
                evenSum += firstNum;
            }` outside of the loop.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Focus on the parts of the term after 'short'.

Comment: Why do you treat the first value so differently? I don't see any reason to handle the first value any differently to the later values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were doing some really weird stuff where the first time a number was entered it was treated as special. This was causing the first even number entered (2, in this case) to be added multiple times to the total.

Put all of your input in the same loop so you can treat everything equally:

```
public static void evenSum(){
    //prompt the user to enter the amount of integers
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("how many integers? ");
    int numbers = console.nextInt();

    int evenSum = 0;
    int evenMax = 0;

    //for loop for the number of times to ask user to input numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
        //input new number
        System.out.print("next integer? ");
        int num = console.nextInt();

        //check to see if the number is even. if it is not even, 
        //we don't care about it at all and just go to the next one
        if (num % 2 == 0){
            //add it to the sum
            evenSum += num;

            //if it's larger than the maximum, set the new maximum
            if (num > evenMax) {
                evenMax = num;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("even sum = " +evenSum);
    System.out.println("even max = " +evenMax);
}
```

As you can see, this code also only checks to see if a number is even once. There is no need to be continuously checking if `num` is even every time you use it: its value is not changing during the duration of a single run of the loop.

Comment: I noticed this was almost all correct except evenSum += firstNum needs to be evenSum += num.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I preserved the wrong line. Good catch, edited to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Move the following code inside the for loop to just before the for loop-

```
if (firstNum % 2 == 0){
        //if it is even then add it to the evenSum
        evenSum += firstNum;
}
```

This will prevent the repeated addition of the first number in the evenSum

Answer (score 0):

You also want

```
if (num > evenMax) {
    if (num % 2 == 0 ) {
        evenMax = num;
    }
}
```

or, alternatively

```
if (num > evenMax && num % 2 == 0) {
    evenMax = num;
}
```

In your scenario, `firstNum` is 2 so every number after it is technically larger, so you will (theoretically) not get the largest even number entered after the first number.

Answer (score 0):

Either move the first if condition inside the for loop upwards (outside of the for loop) 
or store all of the user inputs in a data structure i.e. Array before processing them. 
Storing them in Array would make it easier to manipulate the data.

Comment: "inside the foor loop upwards (outside of the for loop)"... ? I have no idea what you mean by this.

Comment: I meant moving the first if condition inside the for loop to be moved outside of it. is it too hard to understand mr. I think the person who gave me credit for my answer got the point very clearly

Comment: See, I still can't really tell what you're saying here 100%. Grammar, punctuation, and clarity are very important when posting answers.

Answer (score 0):

Working code:-

```
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numbers =0, firstNum =0, num =0 ;        
    System.out.print("how many integers? ");
    numbers = console.nextInt();
    System.out.print("next integer? ");
    firstNum = console.nextInt();
    int evenMax = 0;
    int evenSum = 0;

    if(firstNum%2==0)
    {
    evenSum = firstNum;
    evenMax = firstNum;
    }


    for (int i = 1; i < numbers; i++) {
        System.out.print("next integer? ");
        num = console.nextInt();



    if (num % 2 == 0) {
//don't add firstNum multiple times to the evenSum, earlier it was added every time you entered an even number 
                evenSum += num;

//check if the number you entered, i.e. num greater than the already existing greatest number i.e. evenMax and if so update it
                evenMax = num > evenMax: num?evenMax;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("even sum = " +evenSum);
        System.out.println("even max = " +evenMax);
}
```

Hope this helps. There are three major problems in your code:-

1. The firstNum(if it's even) gets added to the sum every time you enter a even number. i.e. if first number is 4 and the loop runs 10 times and encounter 6 even numbers, then along with the even number 4 also gets added six times. If you want to use it as a special number and get it's value separately then you'll have to add it to the sum before the loop.
2. You should compare every new even number to the previous greatest even number and hence set the value of evenMax. You are comparing them to the firstNum so if the first number is 2 and the last even number is anything greater than two, it would be set as the value of evenMax. Compare every even number to the current maximum even number i.e current value of evenMax.
3. You don't check if the first number is evenor not and assign it to even max. So if it is 999999 it still get's assigned, but it is not even.

Please check it as correct answer and vote up if you find it useful.